# ¿Cómo puedo pedirle al usuario (en python) que ingrese una cantidad X y que esa sea la dimensión de mi lista?

Tags: python, pseint

Estoy aprendiendo fundamentos de programación y justo voy en el tema de PSeint, pseudocódigo y diagramas de flujo.

Para crear listas, en pseint podemos darle la dimensión de la lista, con

```
Dimension lista[3]
```

Esto quiere decir que mi lista tendrá una dimensión de 3 valores. Y si por ejemplo, le pido un input al usuario y lo combino con la dimensión de la lista puedo lograr que el usuario elija sus dimensiones.

algo así como

```
Escribir 'Ingresa la cantidad de toppings por agregar: '
Leer new_toppings_quantity
Dimension new_toppings_list[new_toppings_quantity]
```

Pero no puedo hacer esto en Python, tengo entendido que debe haber algún método para darle la cantidad de entradas que tendrá mi lista.

Sólo logré pedirle al usuario la cantidad de valores que tendrá mi lista, y esta cantidad la puse en Entero

```
new_toppings_quantity = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de toppings por agregar: "))
```

Comment: En Python las listas no tienen largo predeterminado; no necesitas "reservar" espacio.

Answer (score 1):

En Python todo es dinámico y no necesitas "reservar" espacio para las listas (o diccionarios, sets, etc.). Si tienes un nuevo elemento, simplemente lo agregas.

El patrón normal para ingresar una cantidad indeterminada de valores es partir con una lista vacia, entrar en un ciclo infinito donde pidas y agregas valores hasta que se produzca alguna condición que señala el término del proceso:

```
valores = []
while True:"Ingrese valor (ENTER para terminar): "
    valor = input("Ingrese valor (ENTER para terminar): ")
    if valor:
        valores.append(int(valor))
    else:
        break

print(valores)
```

produce:

```
Ingrese valor (ENTER para terminar): 1
Ingrese valor (ENTER para terminar): 2
Ingrese valor (ENTER para terminar): 3
Ingrese valor (ENTER para terminar): 4
Ingrese valor (ENTER para terminar): 5
Ingrese valor (ENTER para terminar): 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

En python las listas son dinámicas, lo que quiere decir que su tamaño no está prefijado, sino que directamente puedes añadirle (o quitarle!) elementos mientras el programa está funcionando. Por tanto no necesitas "declarar" previamente su tamaño.

Por ejemplo, en el caso que planteas, se podría preguntar al usuario cuántos toppings agregar, pero sólo para saber cuántas veces habrá que repetir después el bucle que le pida cada topping y lo agregue a la lista. Por ejemplo:

```
new_toppings_quantity = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de toppings por agregar: "))
lista_de_toppings = []  # La lista empieza vacía
for i in range(new_toppings_quantity):
   topping = input(f"Dame el topping {i}")
   lista_de_toppings.append(topping)
```

Fíjate que gracias a que Python admite listas dinámicas, ni siquiera tendrías por qué preguntar de antemano al usuario cuántos toppings quiere. Puedes simplemente seguir agregando toppings hasta que el usuario introduzca una cadena vacía. Por ejemplo:

```
lista_de_toppings = []
while True:
   topping = input("Introduce un topping (vacío para terminar)")
   if not topping:
       break # Salir del bucle
   lista_de_toppings.append(topping)
```

Si quieres saber cuántos elementos hay en la lista al salir del bucle tienes la función `len()` a la que le pasas la lista (también admite cadenas o cualquier iterable) y te devuelve cuántos elementos tiene.

Verás que Python es más avanzado que PSeint, que está inspirado en lenguajes más antiguos y estáticos, tipo C o Java. Python también podría adaptarse a este uso, pero no se considera buena práctica. Por ejemplo, para escribir un código *poco pythónico* que cree de antemano un array del tamaño prefijado y luego reemplace los valores usando índices (como seguramente harías con PSeint) podrías escribir lo siguiente:

```
new_toppings_quantity = int(input("Ingresa la cantidad de toppings por agregar: "))
lista_de_toppings = [""] * new_toppings_quantity
for i in range(new_toppings_quantity):
   topping = input(f"Dame el topping {i}")
   lista_de_toppings[i] = topping
```

Este código, repito, **está desaconsejado en Python**, y si ves código similar por ahí será un claro síntoma de que su autor lleva poco tiempo con el lenguaje (y mucho tiempo con C). Lo he incluido sólo para que veas que también sería posible.

Aquí la inicialización de la lista se hace con `[""]*new_toppings_quantity`, lo que crea una lista que contiene tantos elementos como indique la variable `new_toppings_quantity`, siendo cada uno de esos elementos una cadena vacía. Después en el bucle cada cadena vacía se reemplazará por un topping.